# Interchanging summations over sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, summation, fubini-tonelli-theorems, alternating-expression

In order to understand two different definitions of the same function $f$ (as stated by Besner, 2022), I am trying to prove that those expressions are equal: 
$\Delta(A) = f(A) - \sum_{B \subset A} \Delta(B)$,      (formula 1) 
$\Delta(A) = \sum_{B \subseteq A} (-1)^{|A|-|B|} \ f(B)$   (formula 2).

I tried doing this by induction on $|A|$. For $|A|=1$, we can clearly see that the statement is true:
$f(A) - \sum_{B \subset A} \Delta(B) = f(A)$ and $\sum_{B \subseteq A} (-1)^{|A|-|B|} \ f(B) = (-1)^0 \ f(A) = f(A)$.

Assuming the statement is true for all $|A|<n$, I try to prove this for $|A|=n$:
$\Delta(A) = f(A) - \sum_{B \subset A} \Delta(B)$ 
$= f(A) - \sum_{B \subset A} \sum_{C \subseteq B} (-1)^{|B|-|C|} \ f(C)$.

This is equivalent to the expression 
$f(A) = \sum_{B \subseteq A} \sum_{C \subseteq B} (-1)^{|B|-|C|} \ f(C)$

Unfortunately, this is as far as I got. Earlier suggestions were to use Fubini's theorem or Newton's Binomium, but I could not figure out whether these suggestions were right and how to use it. Hence, the aim here is to interchange or rewrite the summations in order to arrive at formula 2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this summation is always zero, regardless what $f$ is. So you can simplify that expression by simply writing $0$. If you need a proof, work on induction on $|A|$.

Comment: @Crostul not quite.

Comment: @hans15 "I could not figure it out" well why don't you write down your attempt and then we can look at it and see what's wrong?

Comment: @JBL Thank you for your response. I just added some background information on my question, including my previous attempts and thoughts on this.

Comment: Two comments: (1) surely the base case is $|A| = 0$, not $|A| = 1$, and similarly you have some clear omissions of the empty set in your calculations.  (2) Reversing the order of summation is a great idea.  What happens when you try to do it?

Comment: (a) When reversing the order we get $\Delta (A) = f(A) - \sum_{C \subseteq B} f(C) \sum_{B \subset A} (-1)^{|B|-|C|} = f(A) - \sum_{C \subseteq B} f(C) \sum_{i=1}^{|A|} (-1)^{|A|-i}$ ${|A|}\choose{i}$ right? (b) On what grounds (theorems, rules, ...) would reversing the order of summation be legal here? (c) How would the notation be? Since the first summation asks for a $C \subseteq B$, while $B$ is only picked in the second summation, that's not clear for me yet.

Comment: "right?" no.  So let's start with something simpler, like "normal" sums over intervals of integers.  Can you reverse the order of the sums in $\sum_{n = 1}^4 \sum_{i = 1}^n g(n, i)$?

Comment: (As for how to justify it, all the sums in question are finite; once you figure out how to write the sum over the same set of indices in the other order, the justification will be the commutative property of addition.)

Comment: I now see that $\sum_{n=1}^4 \sum_{i=1}^n g(n,i) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{n=i}^4 g(n,i)$, so also the summation limits change by reversing the order.

Comment: Yes, good.  The same thing has to happen when you reverse an order of summation over sets.  In the integer example, the set of summation indices $\{(n, i) : 1 \leq i \leq n \leq 4\}$ can be broken down by first choosing $n$ and then choosing $i$ (that's $\sum_{n = 1}^4 \sum_{i = 1}^n$ or by first choosing $i$ and then choosing $n$ (that's what you wrote).  The same thing happens in the set version: your summation is over the pairs $\{ (B, C) : C \subseteq B \subseteq A\}$ (where $A$ is fixed before-hand); the sum you start with chooses $B$ first then $C$, and you need to switch the order.